# open selected row in datagridview to edit in Another form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, edit

I am using vb.net designer  to connect to access database .
On my Form1 I have a DataGridView And Two Button For Add And Edit
I Make Form2 To Add Data Into Database And Worked OK ..
Imake Form3 Wiht Same form2 Content
Now I need When i selcet row in DataGridView And Clic Edit Button The data of selected row show on form3 for Edit it

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.SalesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.OrdersDataSet.sales)

    Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = Date.Today
End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    SalesBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("date = '{0}'", DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString())
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Form3.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub SalesDataGridView_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles SalesDataGridView.CellContentClick
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is your question? Please define a clear question so one can answer it. Thanks.

Comment: I need When i selcet row in DataGridView And Click Edit Button The data of selected row show on form3 for Edit it

Comment: @user3077945 .. you can use Dgv currentrow and cell index for that ..

Comment: how ? I am Sorry If this Site Not For Beginner

Comment: @user3077945 .. no, SO is for everyone who need some help .. for your prob, for example you may do like this `txtbox1.Text = dgv.Rows(CurrentRow).Cells("name").Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to approach this in a modal/dialog way. You only need one form for both *add* and *edit*.

**Add/Edit form**

Add a parameterized constructor to the form.

```
Public Sub New(row As DataRowView)
    Me.InitializeComponent()
    'Me.ctlAge: NumericUpDown control.
    'Me.ctlBirthday: DateTimePicker control.
    'Me.ctlName: TextBox control.
    If (row Is Nothing) Then
        'Add mode, set default values:
        Me.ctlAge.Value = 0
        Me.ctlBirthday.Value = Date.Now
        Me.ctlName.Text = String.Empty
    Else
        'Edit mode, set current values:
        Me.ctlAge.Value = CDec(row.Item("AGE"))
        Me.ctlBirthday.Value = CDate(row.Item("BIRTHDAY"))
        Me.ctlName.Text = CStr(row.Item("NAME"))
    End If
End Sub
```

You also need an accept button and a cancel button.

```
Friend Sub btnAcceptClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAccept.Click
    Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Friend Sub btnCancelClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

**Main form**

Add method:

```
Private Sub btnAddClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Try
        Using f As New AddOrEditForm(CType(Nothing, DataRowView))
            If (f.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then

                Dim view As DataView = TryCast(Me.SalesDataGridView.DataSource, DataView)

                If (view Is Nothing) Then
                    Throw New InvalidCastException()
                End If

                Dim viewRow As DataRowView = view.AddNew()

                viewRow.EndEdit()
                viewRow.Item("AGE") = f.ctlAge.Value
                viewRow.Item("BIRTHDAY") = f.ctlBirthday.Value
                viewRow.Item("NAME") = f.ctlName.Text
                viewRow.EndEdit()

            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Edit method:

```
Private Sub btnEditClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    Try

        Me.SalesDataGridView.EndEdit()

        If (Me.SalesDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0) Then

            Dim gridRow As DataGridViewRow = Me.SalesDataGridView.SelectedRows(0)
            Dim viewRow As DataRowView = TryCast(gridRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)

            If (viewRow Is Nothing) Then
                Throw New InvalidCastException()
            End If

            Using f As New AddOrEditForm(viewRow)
                If (f.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
                    viewRow.BeginEdit()
                    Try
                        viewRow.Item("AGE") = f.ctlAge.Value
                        viewRow.Item("BIRTHDAY") = f.ctlBirthday.Value
                        viewRow.Item("NAME") = f.ctlName.Text
                        viewRow.EndEdit()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        viewRow.CancelEdit()
                        Throw ex
                    End Try
                End If
            End Using

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```